# C# Winform: Is Application.Run() useful if I run a Dialog Form ?

Tags: c#

Can I just do in Program.cs

```
Form1.ShowDialog();
```

And in Form1:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

That is I never use Application.Run() like the default VStudio Code ?

Is there any annoyance to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like to stick with the form class methods. `Form.ShowDialog()` and `Form.Close()`. Everything you need is there, including the `Form.DialogResult`. If you stick to just instantiating your forms and using the methods attached to them, it seems a lot cleaner in the long run. I don't feel you would gain anything from using Application.Run() when running a form dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ShowDialog` will create and run its own message loop.  There are actually a lot of different methods you would not even think of that do this.

`Application.Exit` instructs all running message loops to exit.  I do not know enough about your application to make a recommendation either on the usage of this method.  But, in mainstream scenarios I think you will find that its useful is limited at best.

There are definitely times when you do not want to use the default code that VS generates regarding `Application.Run`, but your statement that you never use it is concerning to me.

Comment: I never use it in this context of a Real World Application which starts with a Login Screen.

Comment: Why then would I need to Application.Run in this Context ?

Comment: I think a login screen would be an acceptable reason to rely on ShowDialog at first.  But at some point your code should fall through to an Application.Run to get things going the standard way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but it isn't good design.  Program.cs is what starts up the application and contains the smarts of what it means to start and stop the application.  The form which it runs is a window that the user interacts with and should just contain that code.
For example, what if you later want to include that form in another application?  Well you have to modify it because it calls Application.Exit() which would be problematic.  Furthermore, if you have automated GUI unit tests calling Application.Exit() is not good either.

Comment: I can't see why this would be bad design, I follow the tut here
http://en.csharp-online.net/Application_Architecture_in_Windows_Forms_2.0%E2%80%94Application_Lifetime

In Real World Application where you start with a Login Screen, I can't see how you can keep the form in Memory all the life of the application and consider that a good design ?

My question is rather will I have to do some cleaning stuffs other than just Application.Exit ?

Comment: I would prefer to use the Visual Studio generated code which Microsoft designed than that website (not that the website is worthless, but I trust Microsoft more when it comes to design).

Comment: @ programmernovice If you follow the links advice you still have one form for the life of your application.  You just added a responsibility to close the app to the form class

Comment: @Tyler Microsoft is not one single man and VStudio is probably made easy by marketing department for amateurish code but I doubt pros use the Visual Studio Wizard to build something robust. So if you only rely your answers on Microsoft "Trust", I cannot rely on your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just rely on a call to [Form.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx) to return control to the caller rather than Application.Exit(). If the caller is Program.cs, well then your application will terminate.